# OnBackPress behaving differently in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, back

I have 3 activities: *A*,*B*,*C*. When I click on an item in `RecyclerView` in activity *A* activity *B* will be opened. There are a few `String` values which I have passed from *A* to *B*.
In activity *B* when I click on a button I go to activity *C*. In *C* when I press back button from my phone(android default back button) it comes back normally to activity *B*. But I have also put a back button in `ToolBar` using parent activity. When I press that button it shows me error that the `String` value trying to retrieve in activity B is null. I understand why the error is showing. It's obviously because there is no string passed from C to B to fetch.
But why am I not getting this error when I press back from my phones default button? How can I solve this?

**Activity A**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
intent.putExtra("Recievers_Id", userId);
intent.putExtra("Recievers_Name", userName);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity B**

```
MessageSenderId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");
MessageRecieverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name");
```

**Activity C**

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Getting an error on

```
MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id"); 
MessageRecieverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name");
```

because obviously nothing to fetch... how do i solve this

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: can you share your code for all the 3 activities

Comment: Look to my edited question... if needed more code please ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onClickListener` to the back button of your toolbar:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnCLickListener(new View.OnClickListener){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

If you are getting error for null then try this:

```
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id") != null){
    MessageRecieverId = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Id"); 
}
if(getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name") != null){
    MessageRecieverName = getIntent().getStringExtra("Recievers_Name"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the working of back button on toolbar as:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to understand what happens when user presses navigation up button and what happens when `onBackPressed`.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral#NavigateUp):

> - If the parent activity has launch mode `<singleTop>`, or the up intent contains `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, **the parent activity is brought
>     to the top of the stack, and receives the intent through its
>     onNewIntent() method.**
> - If the parent activity has launch mode , and the up intent does not contain `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`, the parent activity
>     is popped off the stack, **and a new instance of that activity is
>     created on top of the stack to receive the intent**.

Where as when back button is pressed, it navigate, in reverse chronological order, through the history of screens. In this case Activity won't be re-created.

To summarize, the lauch mode of your `ActivityB` in AndroidManifest.xml must be `standard`. In this case the activity will be recreated when you press the navigation up button. But when back button is pressed, `ActivityB` is just brought to front, hence the difference in behavior.

**Solution:**

**Approach 1: handle Up button by yourself**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Approach 2:**

Set launch mode of Activity B to `singleTop` in AndroidManifest.xml. Remember to check the implication of changing the [launch mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode).

> The "standard" and "singleTop" modes differ from each other in just
>   one respect: Every time there's a new intent for a "standard"
>   activity, a new instance of the class is created to respond to that
>   intent. Each instance handles a single intent. Similarly, a new
>   instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new
>   intent. **However, if the target task already has an existing instance
>   of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive
>   the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not
>   created.**

Answer (score 0):

On activity *B* you should check is `Intent` has rquired `Extra`.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
if (i.hasExtra("Recievers_Id")) {
    messageRecieverId = i.getStringExtra("Recievers_Id");
} 
if (i.hasExtra("Recievers_Name")) {
    messageRecieverName= i.getStringExtra("Recievers_Name");
}
```